# Wordpress + GetShopped: cart empty on checkout page for non logged users

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I have a site set up with Wordpress and an eCommerce plugin called GetShopped:

- Go to my Shop
- Add some products to the cart => Products are added OK via Ajax, and the cart is being updated
- Go to checkout (or reload the page)
- Cart is empty
- Add more products => The old cart is updated with 2 elements.
- Still, go to checkout (or reload), and the cart is empty.

Sounds like the cart only works on Ajax calls, but not on full page load.

I tried both in HTTP and HTTPS. 
I see cookie WPSC_CUSTOMER_COOKIE exists and is sent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've discovered that the WPSC_CUSTOMER_COOKIE is not received by the ajax call and is resetting the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my version of the issue. Howefully its the same for you. The cookie was being set, but it was also setting a specific folder for the cookie. The AJAX call was one directory up from where the cookie folder was specified. This cause the cookie to be changed each time, which also created a new user each time and of course reset the shopping cart.

My solution was to set the cookie path for WPSC_CUSTOMER_COOKIE in wpsc-constants.php. Change the definition of WPSC_CUSTOMER_COOKIE_PATH which happens around line 55.

```
define( 'WPSC_CUSTOMER_COOKIE_PATH', '/' );
```